# Refresh div with .load() jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have this jquery plugin function (Vticker)

```
$('#box_car_news .car_news').vTicker({ 
animation: 'fade',
speed: 1500,
pause: 2000,
mousePause: true,
direction: 'up',
showItems: 5,
height:210
});

on my main page i have this <div id="box_car_news"></div>   

in a different page i have          

   <div class="car_news">
    <ul>
      <li>DB data dynanic</li>
          <li>DB data dynanic</li>
          <li>DB data dynanic</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

$('#box_car_news').**load**('module_news.asp');

by "load" function i will load dynamic content of list inside div with id box_car_news

but vticker doesnt works because actually the list code "car_news" doesnt exist on my source code

i would like refresh dinamic contents every a few seconds

Comment: What is not working?  Are there errors?

Comment: You could try to put the Ticker call on the page you're loading with a setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

`showItems` should be a whole number. 5 is valid, 5.5 is not.